# Provision/Upload file from sharepoint 2013 App to host web

Tags: sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

I have a module in my app named `IframeListener`. Under this module I have a `.js` file.

[image]

Now I want to upload this file to a library of my host web. My event receiver code goes below:

```
 private void AddScriptInMasterPage(ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        string hostWebUrl = GetSpAppWebUrl(properties) +"/IframeListener/atish-iframe-listener.js";

        var atishIframeJsUrl = "/Style%20Library/atish-iframe-listener.js";

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(hostWebUrl, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, atishIframeJsUrl, fs, true);
        }
    } 

    private string GetSpAppWebUrl(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        using (var ctx = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, true))
        {
            var web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return web.Url;
        }
    }
```

Problem is in the `hostWebUrl`. It gives me some thing like

```
https://{app-web-url}/IframeListener/atish-iframe-listener.js
```

`FileStream` can not read this kind of path. So it is throwing exception.

What is the way to do this?

My main requirement is uploading file from a module or web app. I am just trying in above way. Alternate suggestion will be ok also.

Comment: This might be best asked on StackOverflow, since the question is really how to get the `FileStream` from a url.

Comment: It's a sharepoint problem also. My main requirement is provisioning file to host web. I am just trying to achieve in this way. I wish there is some best way than mine

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106960/convert-to-stream-from-a-url

Comment: Thanks but did not help. `403`.

Comment: Pass the authentication token with the request?

Comment: Any idea? How can I pass token from remote event receiver? Will be very helpful!

Comment: Since you're using TokenHelper to build your context, you should be able to use it to retrieve the auth tokens.  Once you have those, add the authorization header to the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved it following way

File added in a folder of Web App instead of Module. Then the file path becomes

```
var filePath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + @"Script\at-iframe-listener.js";
```

And now `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)` is happy!!

## Full code becomes

```
    private void AddScriptInMasterPage(ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        var atishIframeJsUrl = "/Style Library/at-iframe-listener.js";

        var filePath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + @"Script\at-iframe-listener.js";

        Web web = clientContext.Web;

        List assetLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Style Library");
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.Load(assetLibrary, l => l.RootFolder);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
        newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        newFile.Url = "at-iframe-listener.js";
        newFile.Overwrite = true;

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadAsset = assetLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
        clientContext.Load(uploadAsset);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```